# iOS Tel Phone Call dialog is not showing

Tags: ios, swift

I don't know what is hapenning but call dialog is not showing and i am getting `canOpenUrl` true

```
    guard let call = URL(string: "tel://0518858888") else { print("number is invalid") ; return }

    UIApplication.shared.open(call, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
    print(UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(call)) // getting true
```

Comment: use `tel:0518858888`

Comment: not working but canOpenURL is true

Comment: It wont work if you're testing on simulator.

Comment: phone app was also crashing , but i restart my iPhone and now it is working again

Comment: @Salman500 can you please check canOpenUrl in ios 10 and later?

Answer (score 0):

```
guard let callUrl = URL(string: "tel:0518858888"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(callUrl) else {
    print("number is invalid")
    return
}

UIApplication.shared.open(callUrl, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

just create a simple function

```
func makeCall(phoneNumber: String) {
    let formattedNumber = phoneNumber.components(separatedBy: NSCharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined(separator: "")
    let phonUrl = "tel://\(formattedNumber)"
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: phonUrl)!
    UIApplication.shared.open(url as URL)
}
```

call makeCall function from where you want

for you code just change

```
 URL(string: "tel://\(0518858888)")
```

will work

Comment: For your code just make a change URL(string: "tel://\(0518858888)")

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
 UIApplication.shared.open(NSURL(string: "tel://\(9999999999)") as URL)
```